# SQL Server Agent Jobs to Run SSIS Package

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a SSIS package which i tried to schedule as a job in SQL Server Agent.

In order to achieve this i have created a Credentials with User having SysAdmin role to the server. Also i have created a proxy account to run the job where the principals added for
SQLServerAgent,SQLServerOperator,SQLServerReader.

While configuring job selected package source as File system and given the package path to execute the same.

Package is running good and updating results to table stand alone but not working when executing via SQL Job.

Error:
 The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0x7D722F8836388B46956B164E33DE8955 (reason: A required privilege is not held by the client).  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0

Fix Tried:  Modified the package security with Encryptallwithpassword and no luck still.

Comment: Does the credential have sufficient privileges on the SQL Server. For example try making the credential (windows account) a local admin on the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SQL Server Agent service account to make sure it has permissions to the database and the folder where the packages are being called from.

The proxy account is the user that the package will run as, so make sure that is selected in the job step.

For package encryption, unless you are saving credentials in the package, you can set the protection level to "DontSaveSensitive".  It sounds like the proxy account will have the permissions you need already assigned.